# Cannot set property '0' of null in React Native ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set up a React Native ref like here, only in a class component:

https://snack.expo.io/PrrDmZ4pk

Here's my code:

```
class DetailBody extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.myRefs = React.createRef([]);
  }

  clickText(index) {
    this.myRefs.current[index].setNativeProps({ style: { backgroundColor: '#FF0000' } });
  }

  render() {

    if (this.props.article.json.results.length === 0) {
      return <Loading />;
    }

    return (
      <View >
        <View>
          <View ref={this.props.highlight} nativeID="some-id" >
            {this.props.article.json.results.map((content, index) => (
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.clickText(index)}>
                <View key={index} ref={el => this.myRefs.current[index] = el}>{content}</View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
```

This should theoretically let me add a background colors when my ref is clicked, much like the snack I linked to above.

However what I actually see is this:

[image: Error]

This seems to be related to .current inside my ref being null, despite passing a default value.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: can you provide the code of `Detail.js` plz ?

Comment: `current[index]` seems to be null

Comment: Detail.js is huge, and I don't see a real point to showing it. The problem is inside this particular class. If I remove the refs, this error does not occur.

Comment: @ParthShah Looking at the snack, shouldn't current[item.id] also be null though?

Comment: `() => clickText(index)` seems wrong. It should probably be `() => this.clickText(index)`?

Comment: @FelixKling You're right, though it does not seem to have anything to do with the above error. I fixed it and everything stayed the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element.`

Haven't really used it this way but I think you might just need to do this in the constructor:

```
this.myRefs = React.createRef();
this.myRefs.current = [];
```

Comment: Is this the most "React" way to do this or is there a better way?

Comment: @CecilRodriguez the docs all point this way, you really only need them in state if you want updates to cause a re-render but in this case you just want refs.

Comment: I've also seen some people not use `createRef` and simply do `this.myRefs = [];` as well.